# multiple nodes of different length - creating a loop

Tags: python, selenium

I want to create a code for this image:

[image]

I'm interested for the loop to click on each of the folder things and loop through everything. The problem I'm facing is that they are of different length. For example, if I click on "Datos.." - the parent folder, I can choose "Sexo" which is just one file, then I need to choose "Edad" but that is a folder in itself and has two files within it. How can I write a code which attempts to check if there are more files within a folder and loop through that.

What I have tried (doing with selenium and xpath):

```
    for x in browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="dtree0"]/div/a[2]'):

        x.click()

        for y in  browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="dtree1"]/div/a[2]'):
            y.click()
```

Comment: Look into `os.walk`  There are a ton of examples.  It walks through a tree file structure recursively.

Comment: @JeffH but this is on selenium python. Will it work?